# System load indicator (CPU/memory/io) in Linux Mint Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

Can I place a system load indicator in the taskbar?

Something similar to this:
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/indicator-multiload/

but for Linux Mint. Ideally, it should display three small bars (with a size proportional to the load), one for total CPU use (sum over all CPU cores), another for RAM memory, and another for hard drive I/O.

Answer (score 0):

https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/88 might be what you are looking for. You can also install it with Preferences > Applets > Available applets (online) and search for System Monitor. Remember to install the dependencies yet and restart Cinnamon.
It has CPU, RAM, swap, network, and load average (similar to disk I/O).